# Install Influxdb 1.8.3 from tar.gz on Mac

Tags: installation, influxdb, tar

Hi there I want to install an old version of InfluxDB on a Mac.  I have found what I think is the right tar.gz file on GitHub (at https://dl.influxdata.com/influxdb/releases/influxdb-1.8.3_darwin_amd64.tar.gz), downloaded and unzipped it.  But with no configure or make file that I can find I don’t know how to install it as all the instructions I can find seem to reference those executables.

As someone who is learning as I go along any help would be much appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use homebrew to install influxdb v1 on macOS,

```sh
brew update
brew install influxdb@1
```

Refer to official [docs](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/introduction/install/?t=macOS) for the detail.

Comment: Thanks.  I have installed using homebrew - and managed to get it running using brew services start influxdb@1.   But now I can’t work out how to get the CLI running - without which I’m somewhat stuck!  I’ve guessed at various command line instructions to no avail.  Any ideas?

Comment: What is the issue? Please be specific when you ask questions, attach screenshots if necessary.

Comment: Hey, seems you posted a new question for the same issue, please accept this answer, so that people can move on to your next one.

Comment: Thanks.  I do now have it running - with help from the homebrew discussion page but it was non-trivial as the old version was “keg only” (whatever that means).  Anyway - sorted now thanks to you pointing me towards Homebrew.